# Stack Overflow Accessing Large Vector

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I'm getting a stack overflow on the first iteration of this for loop

```
for (int q = 0; q < SIZEN; q++)
{
    cout<<nList[q]<<" ";
}
```

nList is a vector of type int with 376 items.  The size of nList depends on a constant defined in the program.  The program works for every value up to 376, then after 376 it stops working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show how nList is populated and defined.

Comment: 376 items is no way "large" :).

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use nList.size() instead of SIZEN as loop control condition?

Comment: Of course it stops working if you try to access elements that don't exist. What exactly is your question?

Comment: <sarcasm>Questions about stack overflow belong on meta.stackoverflow</sarcasm>

Comment: How do you know your problem is a stack overflow. And as others have pointed out, your vector isn't large. Please do not try to pre-diagnose your problem when posting here - just give us the relevant code and the symptoms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "stops working", you mean crashes, then you're probably reading past the end of the buffer. `vector::operator[]` is not range checked, so it will let you shoot yourself in the foot.

If you want to traverse a vector, use an iterator, or at the very least `nList.size()`.

So with least modifications to your code:

```
for (int q = 0; q < nList.size(); q++)
{
    cout << nList[q] << " ";
}
```

or with iterators

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = nList.begin();
     it != nList.end(); ++it) {
  cout << *it << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My initial guess here would be that the vector is less than 376.  The `[]` operator makes no guaratees as to running over the actual vector bounds.  You'd be much, MUCH safer if you used the `at` function:

```
for(int i=0; i < nList.size(); ++i){
  cout << nList.at(q) << " ";
}
```

there, if `q` is outside of the vector it'll throw an exception.  That'll help diagnose this type of runtime problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the you have added 376 elements to the vector by using for example push_back it is normal that the access with values higher than 376 make the program fail, you are accessing surely uninitialized and not managed memory.